# How to search a string in a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

For example I have:

```
char buff[1000];
```

I want to search if the string "hassasin" is in that char array.  Here is what I have tried.

```
char word[8] = "hassasin";
char Buffer[1000]=sdfhksfhkasd/./.fjka(hassasin)hdkjfakjsdfhkksjdfhkjh....etc 
int k=0;
int t=0; 
int len=0; 
int sor=0; 
for (k=0; k<1000; k++){ 
    for (t=0; t<8; t++){ 
        if (Buffer[k]==word[t]) len++; 
        if (len==8) "it founds 0.9.1" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should try to write your own code and then asks if you didn't success.

Comment: I tried but I could not find the true answer

Comment: I don't know how many times I've come across "Closed...This question is unlikely to help any future visitors" and the answer has been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the chararray contains stringend or do not end with \0 you can use these code, because strstr will brake on these ones:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c_to_search[5] = "asdf";

    char text[68] = "hello my name is \0 there is some other string behind it \n\0 asdf";

    int pos_search = 0;
    int pos_text = 0;
    int len_search = 4;
    int len_text = 67;
    for (pos_text = 0; pos_text < len_text - len_search;++pos_text)
    {
        if(text[pos_text] == c_to_search[pos_search])
        {
            ++pos_search;
            if(pos_search == len_search)
            {
                // match
                printf("match from %d to %d\n",pos_text-len_search,pos_text);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           pos_text -=pos_search;
           pos_search = 0;
        }
    }
    // no match
    printf("no match\n");
   return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/2In3mr

Comment: ok but i think this code is find the string even if there are other elements between the necessary letters. in my search I want to find the exact word, no other letters between them. how should I do it?

Comment: this code searches for the exact same word.
if you want to search it with spaces around you can search for " asdf "

Comment: i dont get it every time it founds a matching letter, it is doing  ++pos_search. it does not have to be succesive and when it reaches 4 it says I found.

Comment: no it has to be succesive because the position resets if there is no matching letter with 'pos_text -=pos_search; pos_search = 0;'

Comment: pos_text -=pos_search; what is this doing?

Comment: i got it now, the code is brilliant thank you

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can just use [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) for this:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 char buff[1000];
 char *s;

 s = strstr(buff, "hassasin");      // search for string "hassasin" in buff
 if (s != NULL)                     // if successful then s now points at "hassasin"
 {
     printf("Found string at index = %d\n", s - buff);
 }                                  // index of "hassasin" in buff can be found by pointer subtraction
 else
 {
     printf("String not found\n");  // `strstr` returns NULL if search string not found
 }
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do it manually? without using any methods?

Comment: Yes of course - if this is for a homework exercise then you can just implement `strstr` yourself - it's a very simple function and you'll learn a lot in the process of writing it.